# Why don't you ever see a "anything" over (cable type)?

Tags: converter, digital-communications

Possibly an obvious answer, and I'm new to electronics.

You can easily find converters that convert a specific type of signal to another cable to be decompressed on the other end (example, a VGA over coax converter).

In essence, these devices take an analog (or sometimes digital) signal, convert them to a compressed digital signal, send them down a cable with less wires than the input signal had, and then decompress and output as the original signal (at least close enough to the original signal to be acceptable).

Could you make such a converter where it accepts any signal (up to a limited # of wires), be it composite video, analog audio, digital HDMI, or any signal you can imagine, without the device knowing the specific implementation details?

It'd (virtually) be a set of analog to digital converters & compressors on one end, and then digital to analog converters & decompressors on the other.

Would it simply be prohibitively expensive? Or would this not be possible?

Comment: Possible, but way too expensive. Given that all communication types typically have their own standard jack/plug termination, this device (given current electronic devices) would have to have numerous conversion chips in a box with interchangeable ends for all converted types. This would also slow down data transfer and make the connections less reliable. There won't be "one standard to rule them all" any time soon because as soon as one seems to be dominating, a new one comes along. Also, the wires themselves can be part of the standard (such as twisted pair for ethernet).

Comment: Different transmissions expect specific Wave Impedance which the input has to emulate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand slightly on the obvious "because it's very hard / expensive" answers:

If you know what you're sending, say some digital signal that has a defined form - for argument, say it is some digital data like SPI which may be up to 1MHz string of 1's and 0's. That is easy to convert because you know a 1 or 0 can only arrive at a certain time and last a certain period, and the receiver knows the same and can easily clock the data back out with the correct timing, level, etc.

If you have an "anything" converter and you want to be able to send your stream of 1's and 0's at ~1MHz, you must sample it MUCH faster (maybe 10x or more) to accurately reproduce the waveform at the other end. You also need to accurately measure the amplitude, as you no longer *know* that 0v is 0 and 3.3v is 1, so maybe 1.5v is important too, maybe 33v is, so you have gone from transmitting 1 million bits per second to maybe 10 million multi-bit measurements, many orders of magnitude greater.

If you look at data conversion/transmission operations like sampling & encoding you can fairly quickly prove this to yourself, for example nyquist frequency if you have to accurately reproduce your 1MHz stream of 1's and 0's by sampling rather than being able to rely on the timing of the bits.

Edit to add: An example you can easily try at home; Open a text file, type "hello world" and save it. How big is the file? About 11 bytes hopefully. Now take a screenshot of that text and save it as a full-colour bitmap. How big is it? Waaaaay more than 11 bytes. Why? Because the picture can't know it only contains 11 bytes of information, it is storing the colours of hundreds of pixels at probably 3 bytes per pixel.

Answer (score 3):

"Anything" is simply too broad. Such a system would be too inefficient for any particular application.

There certainly are telemetry systems that will transfer a bunch of analog measurements, a bunch of digital data, and one or more video signals over a radio or cable link, but even these are generally configured for the specific task at hand.

If you have the ability to convert your signals to/from digital at each end, there are many ways of multiplexing a lot of digital data over a single wire, such as Cat5 or coax. Then it's just a matter of allocating the appropriate amount of digital bandwidth to each signal.

Answer (score 1):

Feasible but prohibitively expensive. Most protocols correspond to protocol-specific ICs with hardware-assisted encoding or decoding of the protocol, so that the common protocol A to protocol B conversions are distilled to a very cheap chip.

Answer (score 1):

There's only a limited range over which this would be impossible.  There's an additional gotcha besides the issue of capturing all of the data (limited by bandwidth/bitrate on the 'x-axis' and dynamic range on the 'y-axis').

Many links which you might want to extend or compress have additional limitations which are mutually exclusive with each other.  For instance, at the physical layer, some links are limited by the amount of capacitance in their transmission media or in the transmit and receive electronics, yet others specify a need for I/O protection (against ESD etc.) to meet their compliance requirements - and the latter typically have high parasitic capacitance from the protection devices making transmission of the former impossible.

At higher levels, some links require specific handshaking or feedback across the link.  For instance : CAN relies on superposition for its collision detection to work, many links specify a maximum round trip delay, which drives maximum channel length for the 'anything-to-anything' link to the lowest common denominator.  Many high speed digital links perform on-the-fly transmitter pre-emphasis and receiver equalisation to overcome a 'difficult' channel, but the physical layer performance is still very closely constrained in the interface specification.

That said, there are fibre optic links widely available that do something like what you are suggesting.... they are sufficiently wideband and 'protocol agnostic' to easily transmit DVB-T TV signals, or L-Band satellite up/downlinks, or GPS signals, or any manner of things that occupy the RF spectrum between a few tens of MHz to tens of GHz.  Throw in WDM and you can send them in parallel down a single fibre in both directions.